# How do I listen for specific button presses, and home view user interactions?

Tags: java, android

My application listens for user input from the touchscreen and the buttons, but I would like to listen for interaction with specific items in the homescreen view.  So, for example, I need to listen for the user to tap the menu button, and then to produce output.  Is there a paramater I can pass through the onClick() class?  Or do I need to take another route?

Comment: What language/platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Mtest extends Activity {
  Button b1;
  Button b2;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(myhandler1);
    b2.setOnClickListener(myhandler2);
    ...
  }
  View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // it was the 1st button
    }
  };
  View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // it was the 2nd button
    }
  };
}
```

Or, if you are working with just one clicklistener, you can do:

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
          // it was the first button
          break;
        case R.id.b2:
          // it was the second button
          break;
      }
  }
}
```